# Game Center posting bogus scores - iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, game-center

I'm trying to get Game Center working and it's almost there. The only problem is that the scores posted don't make any sense. This is my post score code:

```
-(IBAction)subScore
{
    {
        GKScore *scoreReporter = [[[GKScore alloc] initWithCategory:@"katplay"] autorelease];

        scoreReporter.value = gcPost;
        NSLog(@"posted");
        NSLog(gcPost);

        [scoreReporter reportScoreWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
            if (error != nil)
            {
                NSLog(@"failed!!!");
                NSLog(gcPost);
            }
        }];
    }
}
```

So I play the game and get my score and view the console where the log says that gcPost = 2500. When I view the leaderboard my score is 100,929,392 Points. I have no idea where that number could have come from.

Am I just missing something basic?

Chris

Comment: What are the types of `GKScore.value` and `gcPost`? How are you reading the score back out from gamecenter?

Comment: I'm not sure about GKScore.value. gcPost is "int *gcPost;". I was fallowing a YouTube tutorial which provided me with all that code. I'm not taking the scored out of gamecenter, I launch the leaderboard window in the app and check it in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just implemented Game Center in my app. You need to convert your integer onto a `int64_t`.  In Objective-C terms, thats a `LongLong`. You can change this:

`scoreReporter.value = gcPost;`

to this:

`scoreReporter.value = [[NSNumber numberWithInt:gcPost] longLongValue];`

I strongly urge you to read the [Apple Documentation on Game Center](http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/gamecenter/). It's a quick and easy read. You can copy most of the code out of there as well.

Comment: Thanks, this worked! I have been using the apple document to copy the code from. I just didn't know much about 64-bit integers.

Answer (score 2):

You mention that gcPost is "int *gcPost".  Surely this should just be "int gcPost"?  You want the actual integer rather than a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

What type is gcPost?  The GKScore.value property expects a value of type int64_t.  My guess is whatever type gcPost is doesn't play nicely with that.  Try doing an explicit conversion from the original type to int64_t.

Comment: I just have it as "int *gcPost;". My knowledge of code is very limited so I'll look into converting to int64_t now. Thanks